# Tweaking my php guestbook

Tags: php, mysql

I want it to show the newest post first then second and so on, how do i manage such thing? and it doesnt show the email address for some reason... :( and last but not least: how do i add like timestamp like yyyy/mm/ddd hh:mm ?

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="#"  action="gpost.php">
<fieldset>
 Namn:<br><input name="gnamn" id="gnamn" type="text" size="20">
 <br>E-post:<br><input name="gemail" id="gemail" type="text" size="20">
<br>Meddelande:<br>
<textarea name="gmeddelande" id="gmeddelande" cols="20" rows="10">  
</textarea>
<br><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sänd">
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$user="my user";
$pass="mypasswor :D";
$dbname="pelle";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Misslyckades att ansluta till mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message FROM guestbook");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<div id="post">
<header><h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3></header>
<p><?php echo $row['email']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['message']; ?></p>
 </div>

   <?php }
   mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

and heres my gpost.php

```
 <?php
 $host="localhost"; 
$user="my usernamen"; 
$pass="my password"; 
 dbname="pelle"; 
 $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
 {
 echo "<h1>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."</h1>";
 }
 $name=$_POST['gnamn'];
 $email=$_POST['gemail'];
 $message=$_POST['gmeddelande'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(name,email,message)  VALUES('$name','$email','$message')";
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 else
 echo "Values Stored in our Database!";
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field called "time" from Type INT to Database, with the value of "time()" php function.

And change your SQL from

```
 mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message FROM guestbook");
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message,time FROM guestbook ORDER BY time DESC");
```

time(): Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).
[time on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

date(): string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time().
[date on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: i have managed it to semi working by just adding the datetime column, however i get the result 0000-00-00 00:00:00 on my guestbook

Comment: to save to datetime save date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) to database;
time() create a number, so your datatype must be INT

Comment: It wont allow me to use the value time() when i add a new column how do i bypass this?

Comment: SQL Field: time INT; PHP - function to database: time(); PHP - function from database : echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['time'] )

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to sort the data, add an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL query.  For example: `SELECT name,message,postedDate FROM guestbook ORDER BY postedDate DESC`  You can order by any data you have, so if you want to order by the date/time that records were posted then you need to record that information in your table.
2. It doesn't show the email because you're not selecting the email.  Select it with the other data: `SELECT name,message,email FROM guestbook`
3. You can add any column you like to your table.  In MySQL you would likely use a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column type.  You can insert into this column just as any other, and select from it just as any other.

Comment: What values should i use on the datetime column? i got name: DATETIME type: datetime value: NULL

Answer (score 0):

To insert the current time into the database when a new entry is made you can make a field with type 'time' and set it to 'TIMESTAMP' and then format it for your output in your PHP. The email isn't showing up because you're not querying it. Change your query to:

```
"SELECT name, message, time, email FROM guestbook"
```

Where 'email' is the name of your email field. Alternatively, if those are the only fields in the table you can shorten it to:

```
"SELECT * FROM guestbook"
```